# Error when creating an FHIR resource in google cloud healthcare API (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, hl7-fhir, google-cloud-healthcare

I'm trying to create a Patient type resource using the service

- **healthcare = Google::Apis::HealthcareV1**
- **service = healthcare::CloudHealthcareService.new**

and ***create_project_location_dataset_fhir_store_fhir*** method in ruby.
I keep on getting this error
**missing required field:** **resourceType**

more details on the function im using: https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/HealthcareV1/CloudHealthcareService.html#create_project_location_dataset_fhir_store_fhir-instance_method

if anyone has come across this and knows how to fix it

this is how i create my request body:

- http_body_object = Google::Apis::HealthcareV1::HttpBody.new
- http_body_object.content_type = "application/fhir+json"
- http_body_object.data = json_encoded
- http_body_object.extensions = extensions

Comment: Can you share the resource in xml or json? The body could be missing the proper resourceType: Patient  as you can find at this link - https://www.hl7.org/fhir/patient-example.json.html

Answer (score 0):

The body could be missing the proper resourceType: Patient as you can find at this link - hl7.org/fhir/patient-example.json.html